# Funny train announcement in Bavarian dialect: What does it mean?

Tags: bavarian

The below paragraph comes from the article “Lustige Geschichten, die Menschen in der Bahn erleben” in *bento.de*:

> Durchsage in gebrochenem Bayrisch in der Münchner U-Bahn: "**So und jetz kemma dann gleich an die Mingara Freiheit, da bitte links aussteign**." Passagiere schauen sich fragend an. Nach dem Schließen der Türen folgt die Durchsage einer anderen Person in perfektem Bayerisch: "**Bitte entschuldigens, da Azubi hätts grod moi probiern woin, mia san uns oba einig, er losst des künftig bleim**".

What do the two sentences highlighted in bold in the above paragraph mean? I couldn't find words like *woin*, *san* or *bleim* in dict.cc or other German dictionaries.

Comment: This joke is almost 100 years old.

Comment: Und wo ist der Witz daran?

Comment: Foreign visitors to Munich may it find interesting that the phrase *Zurückbleim bidde* (Zurückbleiben bitte) used by train drivers in the Munich underground is very specific; probably not to be heard anywhere else.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich vermute, die Situation, dass ein "auswärtiger" Mitarbeiter in einer Durchsage bemüht ist, den lokalen Dialekt anzunehmen, dann aber von einem einheimischen Vorgesetzten scherzhaft für seinen zweifelhaften Erfolg hierbei kritisiert wird, war *vor Ort* durchaus witzig. Freilich geht aber genau die Art, wie der Dialekt wiedergegeben wurde, in der Textfassung verloren, vom Eindruck einer spontanen Handlung der Beteiligten ganz zu schweigen.

Comment: @user unknown When asking the question, I didn't understand what was said in the Bavarian dialect. I assumed the situation should be funny, because the heading of the article reads "Lustige Geschichten ...". So, I started the question with the word "funny". I also agree with the comment above by O.R. Mapper.

Comment: Well, my question, @EugeneStr., was more towards Janka, who called it an old joke, not just funny, so I thought there is some hidden mistake, which could revealed, if the correct bavarian expressions were shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first text means:

"So und jetz kemma dann gleich an die Mingara Freiheit, da bitte links aussteign."

"So und jetzt kommen wir dann gleich an die [Münchner Freiheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchner_Freiheit), da bitte links aussteigen."

And the seccond one:

"Bitte entschuldigens, da Azubi hätts grod moi probiern woin, mia san uns oba einig, er losst des künftig bleim".

"Bitte entschuldigen Sie, der [Azubi](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehrling) wollte es gerade probieren, wir sind uns aber einig, er lässt es zukünftig bleiben.".

The word by word translation of *er hätts grod moi probiern woin* would be: *er hätte es gerade mal probieren wollen*.